# Using provider within alert dialog does not work

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to manage a state "playerList" in two screens:

The code below shows how the provider was built

```
class PlayerList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Player> _playerList = [];

  List<Player> get playerList {
    return [..._playerList];
  }

  void addPlayer(Player player) {
    _playerList.add(player);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deletePlayer(int index) {
    _playerList.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

In screen 1, everything works perfect. However, when I do the same, but then within an AlertDialog, the updated value only shows after closing the dialog and opening it again.

The code below shows the relevant part of the build method.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PlayerList _playerListData = Provider.of<PlayerList>(context);
    List<Player> _playerList = _playerListData.playerList;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                      'Are you sure you want to leave? The current game will be lost.'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true)),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('No'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)),
                  ])),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6ca0dc),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: [
            _playChallenge(_playerList),
          ]),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Player List'),
                    content: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                            0.5, // Change as per your requirement
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                            0.5, // Change as per your requirement
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: _playerList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  _playerList[index].name,
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                                ),
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                                  onPressed: () =>
                                      _playerListData.deletePlayer(index),
                                ));
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a StatefulBuilder and using the Provider.of inside the statefulbuilder. See:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                      'Are you sure you want to leave? The current game will be lost.'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true)),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('No'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)),
                  ])),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6ca0dc),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: [
            _playChallenge(Provider.of<PlayerList>(context).playerList),
          ]),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                    PlayerList _playerListData =
                        Provider.of<PlayerList>(context);
                    List<Player> _playerList = _playerListData.playerList;
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Player List'),
                      content:
                          Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                        Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                              0.5, // Change as per your requirement
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                              0.5, // Change as per your requirement
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: _playerList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    _playerList[index].name,
                                    style:
                                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                                  ),
                                  trailing: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                    color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        _playerListData.deletePlayer(index),
                                  ));
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
```